# Problem getting information from the imdb

Tags: ajax, wordpress, imdb

I'm trying to get movie information from the omdb web service using ajax and wordpress

but the value is zero and works fine when I delete the first two conditions in setApi.php


setApi.php :

```
    function fetch_info(){

        if (isset($_POST['send-movies-nonce'])){
            if (current_user_can('edit_posts')){
                $id_movie = $_POST["id_movie"];
                if(($id_movie != NULL)){
                    $get_json_movie = file_get_contents("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=xxxxxxx&i=$id_movie");
                    $result = json_decode($get_json_movie, TRUE);
                    var_dump($result);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_fetch_info', 'fetch_info');
```

Comment: Are you sure the `$id_movie` is being passed? I tried your api link using this movie id from IMDB `tt1853728` and the data is retrieved.

Comment: Api works but it runs correctly when I delete the first two conditions.

Comment: Then you should probably update the title of your question, as this is not an IMDB issue - it's the rest of your code. Check each condition to see where it's failing. Is the the first or the second. You can also combine both of those into one condition.